# Is there a way to open and close a stream easily at kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

What I have to do at java:

```
try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/user/123.txt")) {

    byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(bytes);
    System.out.println(new String(bytes));


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But `kotlin` doesn't know about `try-with-resources`! So my code is

```
try {
    val input = FileInputStream("/home/user/123.txt")
} finally {
    // but finally scope doesn't see the scope of try!
}
```

Is there an easy way to close the stream ? And I don't speak only about files. Is there a way to close any `stream` easily ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`Closeable.use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) is what you're looking for:

```
val result = FileInputStream("/home/user/123.txt").use { input ->
    //Transform input to X
}
```

Comment: Does it also flush the stream?

Comment: Of course not. Just check the source code.

Answer (score -4):

```
 BufferedInputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/user/123.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        }
```

Works fine with any Inputstream. This is just an example i used.

Comment: This is java code